# How to automate configuration of Windows Defender Firewall for a specific GPO in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, gpo

I want to configure with PowerShell
**Group Policy Management Editor** -> **domain.local** -> **Group Policy Objects** -> **MyGpo** -> **Computer Configuration** -> **Windows Settings** -> **Security Settings** -> **"Windows Defender Firewall With Advanced Security - LDAP:\....."** setting for my specifc GPO so that

-DefaultInboundAction Block
-DefaultOutboundAction Allow
–NotifyOnListen True
-AllowUnicastResponseToMulticast True

[image]

But I cannot find the right command for that.. I was using

```
Set-NetFirewallProfile -PolicyStore "universitetas.local\Group Policy Objects\BazinėsUgniasienėsTaisyklės" -DefaultInboundAction Block -DefaultOutboundAction Allow –NotifyOnListen True -AllowUnicastResponseToMulticast True -Enabled True
```

But it gives me an error...

```
Set-NetFirewallProfile : The parameter is incorrect. 
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sukonfiguruotiFirewalla.ps1:42 char:1
+ Set-NetFirewallProfile -PolicyStore "universitetas.local\Group Policy ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_NetFirewallProfile:root/standardci...FirewallProfile) [Set-NetFirewallProfile], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 87,Set-NetFirewallProfile
```

I'm pretty sure my command is almost correct but it lacks something.

Comment: Have you tried using the powershell version of $true? Seems you’re passing a string “true” instead

Comment: You need to re-type the hyphen for parameter `NotifyOnListen`. As it is now, you have a [En-dash](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html) in front of it where it should be a minus `-`

Comment: Hello @Adomas does the above suggestion works for you? or if not you can refer this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/set-netfirewallprofile?view=windowsserver2022-ps) : to know to specify the policy store if any thing missing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You [**Theo**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) for providing the suggestions. Converting this an answer to help other community members if they encounter the same problem in future.

I was also getting the same error if i am trying with your code. You need to use `hyphen` in place of `en-dash`.

You will notice the difference you will write `en-dash` and `hyphen` on NotePad.

[image]

***Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/set-netfirewallprofile?view=windowsserver2022-ps***